# List files and paths in a VB poject

Tags: vb.net, file, project

I have several VB.Net projects each with containing many files/forms.  Several of the forms are shared/linked between more than one project and saved in a shared folder.  Recently I discovered one file that should have been shared was not, meaning that there were two files with the same name in two different folders.  Obviously any change of a file in one project was not shown in the other poject. Is there any way of listing all the files and paths in a project - either to screen or spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at the projectname.vbproj file, it is a xml file and in the node called   `<ItemGroup>` you are going to find what you are looking for, you can tell if a file is a linked one if inside the `<Compile>` node there is a `<Link>` tag.

Comment: Unless this is a new SDK-style project file. This kind of project file just assumes that all code files in the project folder and its subfolders belong to the project without listing them explicitly.

Comment: Thanks.  But it works but needs quite a bit of editing to get the lists.  For several projects it lists the files in the 'CommonLinked' folder which makes it easy to see if any files are missing.